# installing Lubuntu directly from a USB

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, usb, lubuntu

I downloaded the Lubuntu 20.04.1 .iso and wrote it out to a USB drive. I can boot from that drive and am presented with the following choices:

- Start Lubuntu
- Start Lubuntu (safe graphics)
- Test Memory
- Boot from first hard drive

I know that if I boot into live mode, there will be an icon on the desktop to allow me to install to my hard drive. I'd like to cut out the middle man and install from the USB to the hard drive without having to go through the "Trying Out" method first.

Now the weird thing is that when I open up grub.cfg I see 3 menu entries:

- Start Lubuntu
- Start Lubuntu (safe graphics)
- OEM Install (for manufacturers)

Why does GRUB not show me the OEM Install menu item?

And more importantly, I'm creating a respin off of Lubuntu. What do I tell GRUB so that there's an option to directly install instead of just running in live mode?

Comment: If you boot the same thumb-drive on a newer system (uEFI or secure boot enabled) you'll see that option offered. Your hardware will dictate what options are shown, your hardware doesn't match what is considered for OEM install.

Comment: @guiverc You are correct! I was booting a BIOS system and did not have the OEM Install option. On a UEFI system I see it. Is this being controlled from grub.cfg because the menu entries don't make a distinction between BIOS/UEFI. I also notice that on Ubuntu, I get a Try/Install dialog when I first start up. This seems weird since the grub.cfg looks identical to Lubuntu. How do I make the Try/Install dialog come up on LUbuntu?

Comment: The boot process is handled by cdimages (in package/launchpad terms) and that decision is made pre-grub's involvement (grub will boot the system post-installation of course). I don't understand the system in any way helpful to you sorry, I'm involved in QA for Lubuntu thus pick up when there are problems due to changes (lots of late) with cdimages & grub detected in *daily* images, but much of the detail in bug reports goes beyond me.

Comment: Try adding `only-ubiquity` to your boot process, either at the end of the linux line in the grub.cfg menuentry or in txt.cfg or syslinux.cfg if you are booting syslinux

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Yes, I added only-ubiquity and I got the option to do a real install. Thanks.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron please add an answer, I for one, want to upvote!

Comment: @guiverc: Thank you, I hope I did not make a simple thin sound too complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Install Ubuntu Option when Booting from USB

To ensure that the Install Ubuntu option is available when booting from a Live/Persistent USB the expression `only-ubiquity` to the boot process.

For GRUB2, a menuentry may be added to grub.cfg:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

For Syslinux, edit syslinux.cfg or /isolinux/txt.cfg depending on which is used.

```
label live-install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd quiet splash ---
```

`only-ubiquity` can be added during a GRUB2 boot by pressing `e` when the menu appears and typing `only-ubiquity` at the end of the line that starts with `linux`.

`only-ubiquity` can be added during a syslinux boot by pressing the `shift` key, the `ESC` key at language, the `F6` key and the `Esc` key again, type a space and then `only-ubiquity`.

This will activate the installer for only that session.

Syslinux usually has `only-ubiquity` built in. **mkusb** uses it in the GRUB boot menu.